# PIC16F628A to Arduino RF Communication Fails (433MHz)

Tags: arduino, communication, pic, mikroc

I have pic16f628a and Arduino UNO...

I use MikroC for PIC...

I use 433 mhz transmitter and receiver.

My purpose is reading datas from Arduino UNO which I send from PIC16F628A; but I couldn't success it...

The circuit of PIC16F628A (Transmitter):
[The circuit of Transmitter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8LQL.png)

I connected first pin of receiver to +5V of Arduino;

second pin of receiver to 12.pin of Arduino,

last pin of receiver to GND pin of Arduino.

Transmitter(PIC16F628A):

```
char pre[15]={'U','U','U','U','U',255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0}; //start bytes...
char ileri[3]={'f','r','w'};
char geri[3]={'b','c','k'};
char dur[3]={'d', 'u', 'r'};
char i=0,j=0;

void kurulum()
{
 CMCON= 7;
 TRISB= 2;

 UART1_Init(2400);

 delay_ms(100);

}

void main()
{

 kurulum();

 while(1)
       {


          for(i=0;i<15;i++)
                           {
                            UART1_Write(pre[i]);
                           }
          for(j=0;j<10;j++)                   
          {
                          for(i=0;i<3;i++)
                          {
                           while(!UART1_Tx_Idle());
                           UART1_Write(ileri[i]);
                          }
          }


          //*************************************************************


          for(i=0;i<15;i++)
                           {
                            UART1_Write(pre[i]);
                           }
          for(j=0;j<10;j++)
          {
                         for(i=0;i<3;i++)
                         {
                          while(!UART1_Tx_Idle());
                          UART1_Write(geri[i]);
                         }
          }

             for(i=0;i<15;i++)
                           {
                            UART1_Write(pre[i]);
                           }
            for(j=0;j<10;j++)
            {
                           for(i=0;i<3;i++)
                           {
                            while(!UART1_Tx_Idle());
                            UART1_Write(dur[i]);
                           }
            }

       }
}
```

Receiver (Arduino):

```
// receiver.pde
//
// Simple example of how to use VirtualWire to receive messages
// Implements a simplex (one-way) receiver with an Rx-B1 module
//
// See VirtualWire.h for detailed API docs
// Author: Mike McCauley (mikem@airspayce.com)
// Copyright (C) 2008 Mike McCauley
// $Id: receiver.pde,v 1.3 2009/03/30 00:07:24 mikem Exp $

#include <VirtualWire.h>

const int led_pin = 13;
const int receive_pin = 12;

void setup()
{
    delay(1000);
    Serial.begin(9600); // Debugging only
    Serial.println("setup");

    // Initialise the IO and ISR
    vw_set_rx_pin(receive_pin);
    //vw_set_ptt_inverted(true); // Required for DR3100
    vw_setup(2400);  // Bits per sec

    vw_rx_start();       // Start the receiver PLL running

    pinMode(led_pin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    uint8_t buf[VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
    uint8_t buflen = VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN;

    if (vw_get_message(buf, &buflen)) // Non-blocking
    {
    int i;

        digitalWrite(led_pin, HIGH); // Flash a light to show received good message
    // Message with a good checksum received, dump it.
    Serial.print("Got: ");

    for (i = 0; i < buflen; i++)
    {
        Serial.print(buf[i], HEX);
        Serial.print(' ');
    }
    Serial.println();
        digitalWrite(led_pin, LOW);
    }
}
```

I tried this code; but it didn't work...
There is another code;

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(2400);


}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0){
      Serial.println(Serial.read());
    }

}
```

Before trying it; I connected data pin of receiver to RX pin of Arduino...

I usually got '0' byte.i

It didn't work as I desired...

Comment: first test both sides independently using a receiver or transmitter which is known to work properly. When you have both sides working try to wire them up together, chances are that it will not work, so you'll have to investigate connection settings (baud, parity, the wiring itself etc..)

Comment: Thanks; I have already tried both of modules with two pics before and It worked...
How can I wire them up together ?

Comment: Make sure they use the same baud rate and everything. Do they work on the same voltage Levels?  Connect gnd together and the tx line of one to rx line of the other

Comment: Thanks; the problem is solved...
Apparently It was already working well.
The explanations are at the answer I wrote...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***SOLVED***

The tests I have done so far were already taking the true datas but I was viewing them as numbers...

That's why I couldn't understand that It was working well.

Let's have a look at codes;

Transmitter:

> The same as transmitter code at question message

Arduino (Receiver):

```
char x, msg[6];
int i= 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(2400);


}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0){
      msg[i] = Serial.read();
      if (msg[0]=='f' || msg[0] == 'b' || msg[0] == 'd'){
          i++;
        }
      if (i==3){
          Serial.println(msg);
          i = 0;
          msg[0]=0;
        }
    }

}



msg[0]=='f' || msg[0] == 'b' || msg[0] == 'd'
```

The purpose of comparison above is catching "frw", "bck" or "dur" messages which I sent transmitter...

The data pin of the receiver should be connected RX pin of the Arduino...